# Calling an ASP.NET server side method via jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, asmx

I'm trying to call a server side method from client side via jQuery. My code is as follows:

Server side:

```
    using System.Web.Services;
    [WebMethod()]
    //[ScriptMethod()]
    public static void SendMessage(string subject, string message, string messageId, string pupilId)
    {
        //Send message
    }
```

Client side:

```
$("#btnSendMessage").live("click", function(){
  var subject = $("#tbSubject").val();
  var message = $("#tbMessage").val();
  var messageId = $("#hdnMessageId").val();
  var pupilId = $("#hdnPupilId").val();

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./MessagePopup.aspx/SendMessage",
      data: ("subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message + "&messageId=" + messageId + "&pupilId=" + pupilId),
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
          alert(textStatus);
      },
      success: function(result){
         alert("success");
      }
   });
   return false;
});
```

I've added a break point on the server side SendMessage method, but it's never hitting it, but when I run the code the jQuery success method is called. What could be causing this?`

Comment: and code inside the SendMessage is not running, or just can't debug it?

Comment: Both, the SendMessage code isn't running and I can't debug it.

Comment: Is your server side method really an ASPX page and not ASMX or WCF web service? URL points to aspx web page.

Comment: Yeah my server side method is inside an ASPX page, should I create a seperate ASMX or WCF webservice?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To call ASP.NET AJAX "ScriptServices" and page methods, you need to use the full $.ajax() syntax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MessagePopup.aspx/SendMessage",
  data: "{subject:'" + subject + "',message:'" + message + ",messageId:'" + messageId + "',pupilId:'" + pupilId +"'}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

See this post for details on why that's necessary: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Edit: The extension doesn't change to .asmx but remains .aspx.

Comment: Got it working, only difference on this code is the url was MessagePopup.aspx, not asmx.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Dave Ward: thanks so much for making examples that work right out of the box!

Comment: Can you please provide some insights on my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752213/why-is-asmx-giving-an-error-when-pulling-data-using-client-script. Thanks. Mine is an `.asmx`

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you're trying to make use of a page method.

Take a look here [Page Methods in ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) for help

Comment: I didn't know about Page Methods +1

Answer (score 2):

You should use web service instead of regular aspx web page. Web pages has no support to call web methods, I believe your jQuery request loads the HTML page instead. I suggest you two things:

1. Use Fiddler2 (with IE) or HttpFox (with Firefox) to debug AJAX requests and responses on client side.
2. Use WCF web service on the server side. in this case you can use [SvcConfigEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) and [SvcTraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to configure and debug web methods on the server side.

Comment: Why do you say WCF rather than ASMX?

Comment: WCF is now primary and recommended communication technology for .NET. It has a tons of capabilities over asmx web servives, better testability (Google for "Unit testing WCF services").
Strategically, WCF is a right choice to learn. Check this post for more about asmx vs WCF:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dotnetstocktradersampleapplication/thread/048d8a45-dad8-431f-886c-9aae78862285

Comment: Also, you can check Microsoft performance benchmarks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "MessagePopup.aspx/SendMessage",  
        data: "{subject:'" + subject + "',message:'" + message + ",messageId:'" + messageId + "',pupilId:'" + pupilId +"'}",  
        async: true,  
        cache: false,  
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function() {},  
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert(thrownError); }  
     });
```

If this doesn't work...and gives "Syntax Error: syntax error"...then add this

```
<httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,
System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory,
System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler,
System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions,
Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>
```

between `</compilation>` and `</system.web>` in your Web.Config file.

Hope this will help somebody because took me a while to figure that beside jquery function i have to add that in Web.Config.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that might work in your situation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the button.
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            //get the string from the textbox
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "testSearch.aspx/GetMyShippingDate",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'tracking_num': '" + $("#txtTrackingNumber").val() + "'}",  
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (date) {

                    // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                    Success(date);

                },
                error: Failed
            });
        });
    });

     function Success(result) {  
          $("#ParcelShippingDate").html(result.d);
      }  
      function Failed(result) {  
          alert(result.status + " " + result.statusText);  
      }
```

There is an example that has always work for me.

Here is the complete article http://www.webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/How-to-use-jquery-ajax-in-asp-dot-net-web-page.aspx

It works well for those that want a straight forward way of using the jquery asp.net method call back