# Calling Pagemethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hi i have the following pagemethod, however it dues not seem to be working, i tried debugging it and it does not hit the method. Here is what my method looks like;

```
function InsertStatus() {

  var fStatus = document.getElementById('<%=txtStatus.ClientID %>').value;
  PageMethods.InsertStatusUpdate(fStatus, onSucess, onError);

  function onSucess(result) {
      alert(result);
  }

  function onError(result) {
      alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
  }
}
```

And my codebehind;

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string InsertStatusUpdate(string fStatus)
    {
        string Result = "";
        int intUserID = -1;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
          HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/login");
        else
            intUserID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fStatus))
            return Result = "Please enter a status";
        else
        {

            //send data back to database

            return Result = "Done";

        }

    }
```

When i click my button it goes straight through the onError Method. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong?
I found the problem i needed a    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] above the method, due to the fact it is being called by a script. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521352/calling-asp-net-code-behind-function-from-javascript/2521409#2521409

Comment: Do you have a script manager on the page with client methods enabled? That might be why your breakpoint on the server never gets hit.

Answer (score 1):

If I were to guess, I would focus on this:

```
 intUserID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

The best way to solve this is set a breakpoint and start walking through the code. When you run a line and are redirected to the error page, you have found your problem.

The reason I picked that line, is the user is a string. Now, it may be your users are numbers, but it could also be including a domain user == "mydomain/12345", which is not an integer, even if the user part of the string is.

Comment: hi my user is a number i have verified that in another method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't `Response.Redirect` in a `PageMethod`.

Return a string of the redirect URL and then use JavaScript `document.location.href` to handle the redirection.

---

**EDIT:** I've just seen that you tried debugging and the method isn't hit: ensure your `ScriptManager` has `EnablePageMethods` set to `true`:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```

Comment: Hi i have set the enablepagemethods, still nowthing, it is in a masterpage does this matter?

Comment: [Yes](http://weblogs.asp.net/muhanadyounis/archive/2008/12/30/scriptmanager-and-masterpage-pagemethods.aspx).