# Insert Data To Database When We Try To Close The Browse

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, events

I am trying to find a way to catch browser close event and call a server side code for database entry.

I have tried Javascript for window.onbeforeunload and body.onunload but unload event is fired every time the page navigates.

I need to catch only browser close event.

I am using asp.net with C# and my page have a master page.

Comment: Please post your code, you can edit your question and paste in the additional code. Don't forgot to use the code-format button

Comment: you are probably safer either changing your navigation so that it doesn't do entire page posts or just saving the data each navigation. I don't think there is another event other than either beforeunload or unload.

Comment: Don't you need to check for onunload as well? What if the user enters some other URL directly and then closes the browser? (I guess off the top of my head I can't imagine a reason to care that the user is closing the browser that wouldn't also apply if they are navigating away from my page.)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the code in one of these answers to call a function in your code-behind (that writes to DB)

[Calling ASP.NET Code Behind function from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521352/calling-asp-net-code-behind-function-from-javascript/2521409#2521409)

Also, you can do client-side postbacks, [explained on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)