# Textbox.text always returns empty string in code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Well, I'm trying to do a simple command: get the text from TextBox. I've searched for that, but every answer failed for me.

In my code aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
    <div class="form">

        <div class="form-search ngen-search-form">

            <span id="search-trigger" class="form-search-submit">
                <img src="Imagens/Lupa_Icon 2.png" id="lupa"/>
            </span>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxSearch" runat="server" CssClass="form-search-input" placeholder="Pesquise..." ViewStateMode="Enabled"/>

        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

I have a Javascript function that verifies what key my client pressed:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13){

            if( document.getElementById("txtBoxSearch").value == "" ) return true;

            else {

                <% setSearch(); %>

                document.getElementById("testeArv").innerHTML='<%=search.ToString()%>';

                return false;

            }

        }// First if

});
```

And finally, my function *setSearch()* in code behind is:

```
public void setSearch( )
{
    if( !Page.IsPostBack ) {

        search = txtBoxSearch.Text;

    }
}
```

Comment: `string search = txtBoxSearch.Text;`

Comment: I declared _search_ an instance variable.

Comment: setSearch will not run when your else is running, but on the server when the the html is generated from aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main mistake is about how to call codebehind method in jQuery. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521375/4703082)
to know how to do it. Summary: you need **ajax**

Then you will have to keep in mind that it does `Page.IsPostBack`.

With `!Page.IsPostBack` you are saying "first page access" but when you press the button `!Page.IsPostBack` will be false. If you try the same example so:

```
public void setSearch( )
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
        // First page access
        search = txtBoxSearch.Text;
    } else {
        // The page has been reloaded
        search = txtBoxSearch.Text;
      }
}
```

It will work. (The `else` will run)

I am not sure but I have tried it (without jQuery) with a button and the same error occurs. You want to run the function when the Enter is pressed so the page will do the reload. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209903/asp-net-page-enter-key-causing-post-back).

Maybe it helps you in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `<form>` tag blocking your way to get the value in post back. Remove the `<form`> tag and use `AutoPostBack=true` for your text box. You won't need to use jQuery to catch the event and the value.

Answer (score -2):

You can't call code behind code from client-side code. They execute on different machines.

Comment: Why are you down voting this answer. It is correct.

Comment: Yes you can using AJAX @Paul in Seattle

Comment: Of course you can using Ajax @ricopo but that is NOT what the original post was doing so your statement makes no sense. Another misinformed comment. Sigh.