# call method in code behind from JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am trying to execute a method in ASP.NET from Jquery

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MyMessages.aspx?id=66&epslanguage=sv/test",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function(xhr, err) {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            },
        success: function() {
            alert("it works" );
        }
    })
```

code behind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    protected void test()
    {
        test.Text = "works";
    }
```

I get errormessage redayState: 4 and status 200 when I do this. I don't understand the problem. I am vey new at this. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling ASP.NET server side method via JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

`data: "{}",` should be just `data: {},` or just remove it if not in use,,..

Answer (score 0):

as a first your method should be static and public 
so instead of this

```
   [WebMethod]
protected void test()
{
    test.Text = "works";
}
```

it should be

```
[WebMethod]
public static void test()
{
    test.Text = "works";
}
```

this is the first fix 
the second you can't access the test.text 
so if u wanna make sure it works you can 
write it in this way

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "MyMessages.aspx/test",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xhr, err) {
    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        },
    success: function() {
        alert("it works" );
        // and here use jQuery to set the control test
        $("#<%=test.ClientID%>".text("Works");
    }
})
```

so your final code should be like this

```
 [WebMethod]
public static void test()
{
    //test.Text = "works";
}
```

and Ajax method

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "MyMessages.aspx/test",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(xhr, err) {
    alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
    alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        },
    success: function() {
        alert("it works" );
        // and here use jQuery to set the control test
        $("#<%=test.ClientID%>".text("Works");
    }
})
```

I did change the URL for u 
and if you wanna pass parameters you pass them on Data Section of Ajax method 
some thing like this

```
    '{"fname":"' + fname + '","lname":"' + lname + '","email":"' + email + '","address":"' +
```

I wish it helps you 
     address   + '"}'