# How to call C# method from standard HTML input

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Ok, so I've got some HTML that's generated dynamically.  Part of it

```
StringBuilder.Append("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"Email_Clicked\" value=\"Email\" class=\"button\" runat=\"server\" />");
```

I need this to call C# method `Email_Clicked`

How can I accomplish this without `asp:button` control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call ASP.NET Function From Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713/call-asp-net-function-from-javascript)

Comment: @Stuart Dunkeld - That question is similar, but this is not an exact dup.  I dont care if the solution is AJAX, as long as it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing an ajax call to a method in your `aspx` page with jQuery? Take a look at this post about [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, Ajax is easy to implement and will do the trick. Put this attribute on your method:

```
<Ajax.AjaxMethod(Ajax.HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)> _
        Public Function DoSomething() As Integer
            'handle stuff
        End Function
```

you can call the method from javascript by using this:

```
Declaration.DoSomething()
```

don't forget to register your ajax call object in for example the pageload:

```
Ajax.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(GetType(Declaration))
```

If you don't register it, calling Declaration.DoSomething() won't work.

Comment: This looks like a good solution.  Is the "Ajax.AjaxMethod()" assembly available as a seperate download somewhere?

Comment: i'm not sure where my company got it, but i thought you could download it, like discussed in this post: http://forums.asp.net/t/1383384.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't.. directly.

You can use Page Methods or plain AJAX for this though.

Here is relevant question here combining both:
[Calling an ASP.NET server side method via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can "manually" force a postback by calling the `__doPostBack` method in JavaScript. The following web page contains a short tutorial on how to do that:

- [How postback works in ASP.NET](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=18)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
onserverclick="Email_Clicked"
```

Comment: I tried this before I posted on SO.  I could not get it to call the method, never hit breakpoint.