# Calling ASP.NET function using JQuery $.AJAX call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, jquery

My page contains the following code in the function called when a button is clicked:

```
$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: "ProviderPortal.aspx/ppTransferToProvider",   
    data: "{ICA_Key:'" + ICAKey + "', PROV_Key:'" + Provider + "'}",   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,           
    cache: false,    
    dataType: "json",   
    success: function(msg) {     
        alert(msg) 
    } 
});
```

This code is modeled after the selected answer to  [Calling an ASP.NET server side method via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

However, I'm not sure if the ASP.NET (VB, Net 2.0) function signature

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ppTransferToProvider( _
    ByVal ICA_Key As String, _ 
    ByVal Prov_Key as String) As String
```

on the page will receive the data as distinct parameters, or as a string that will have to be parsed for these values. Also, I can't determine if the call is even being made correctly; it seems that a breakpoint in the function itself is never getting hit, so I can't see it for myself.

a) Are parameters passed as just a big string, or are they correctly passed to my function with two parameters?
b) How can I trace the execution of the ASP.NET function? Or is it possible to trace, given that it's shared?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you're passing a `string` while you're service is expecting a set of objects.  Try the following instead

```
data: {ICA_Key: ICAKey, PROV_Key: Provider },
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! Do you know if it's possible to add a breakpoint in the shared function and trace its execution?

Comment: @taserian yes it's possible. It shouldn't be any different than a normal function.  Note: I just realized it was a `Shared` method. It may need to be a non-shared method in order to work properly as part of the web service.  I don't know for sure though.

Comment: Er, no. The data property must be enclosed in strings. The way this was written in the original question is correct, save for the PROV_Key property.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to pass objects, bite the bullet and use [`JSON2.stringify`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).  You can then work with js object and now worry about string manipulation, quotes, parsing..etc:

```
var exmapleParams = {ICA_Key: ICAKey, PROV_Key: Provider };

$.ajax({   
    type: "POST",   
    url: "ProviderPortal.asmx/ppTransferToProvider",   
    data: JSON2.stringify(exmapleParams),   
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,           
    cache: false,    
    dataType: "json",   
    success: function(msg) { //ms web services return .d
        alert(msg.d) 
    } 
}); 

<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function ppTransferToProvider( _
    ByVal exmapleParams As CustomObject) As String
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to stringify! As a neophyte to JSON in general, this is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I'm not sure if the ASP.NET (VB, Net 2.0) function signature [...] on the page will receive the data as distinct parameters, or as a string that will have to be parsed for these values

You'll get distinct values. Your `data` property in your `$.ajax` call *may* need to be changed from:

```
data: "{ICA_Key:'" + ICAKey + "', PROV_Key:'" + Provider + "'}",
```

to:

```
data: "{ICA_Key:'" + ICAKey + "', Prov_Key:'" + Provider + "'}",
```

I say *may* only because I don't know if VB.NET is case sensitive in this regard, but C# does require the case of the JavaScript object's property to exactly match the parameter in the AJAX WebMethod.

Note that your VB function expects variables named `ICA_Key` and `Prov_Key`. If the name `PROV_Key` is correct, then you likely need to rename your VB parameter to match what you're passing.

> b) How can I trace the execution of the ASP.NET function? Or is it possible to trace, given that it's shared?

You can trace the execution of your WebMethod, but you do need to remove the `shared` keyword (From my understanding, `shared` in VB is equivalent to `static` in C#, so my answer is based off that).

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the <WebMethod()> decorator only works with Shared (static) functions, from what I've read.

Comment: The examples in MSDN don't include that keyword, and none of my WebMethods use the static keyword. I changed them to static to test my `$.ajax` calls, and they stopped working with that keyword.

Comment: It's my mistake above. It's not an asmx web service, but an aspx page. Since the page class can be instantiated, the Shared keyword is needed, but that breaks my traceability.

Comment: Ah, okay. Is there any reason why you need it to be on an aspx page? It's my understanding that, although asmx web services are legacy, there's more support for them than aspx page methods.

Comment: There are asmx webservices in use here, but they all require credentials from Active Directory, which users of the Provider Portal won't have. The WebMethod function I'm using impersonates an authorized user to call the required webservice, adding a degree of separation from the web service methodology in use here.

Comment: Hm, okay -- you certainly know your system better than I do. :) Does my other suggestion (about the case of PROV_Key vs. Prov_Key) get you anywhere?

Comment: I changed it around to use Rick Schott's JSON.stringify to pass the parameters. Makes mor much easier unwinding. Still, thank you for sticking around!

Comment: You're definitely right. I `stringify` all my objects if I have more than two parameters (this is just an arbitrary line I drew in the sand for myself). If you need any sort of validation, you can leverage the stringified class's existence and build in validation functions (which I would **HIGHLY** suggest you do). In any case, glad to help!