# Can't access ASMX web service manually in browser but it works using  jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm new to JQuery and Web Services. My question is (in the following code), why does **url: "WebService1.asmx/WebMethod"** work through this JQuery code but if I type that URL directly in my browser, it says the path cannot be found? I have to manually click on the "Invoke" button for the service in the browser in order to call the method and then it navigates to WebService1.asmx/WebMethod.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService1.asmx/WebMethod",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg.d);
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert("got an error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling ASP.NET server side method via JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST and GET! The service is listening for different HTTP verbs and responding accordingly.

Pressing the Invoke sends a POST message to the service while typing it in the bar sends a GET message to the service.

Change the query with : type: "GET", and you'll see.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `ajax` call, you are invoking the url as `POST` request. Whereas while accessing the url directly in browser, you are invoking the url as `GET` request. Your service may accept POST request with empty json array as a parameter which is missing while invoking as GET request.