# Date based validations in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My requirement is like so.

I need to maintain a holiday list. For that I need some validations while saving/editing an entry.

My DB contains a table with HolidayDate column. I have a textbox(jquery date picker) in the page. If the date what I choose has already been saved to the table, I should display an alert message.

Can anyone help me soon, please? Thanks in advance.
Aishvarya.

Comment: You need custom validator which can have both client and server functions to be called. Of course, for client side, Ajax needs to be used.

Comment: you need to use server side code on text change of the texbox. Use Jquery ajax for this. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

Comment: Maybe you can give some more details? Do you want to do this server-side or client-side? Do you want to do a postback or do this via AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateControl" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID ="DateValidator" runat ="server" ControlToValidate="DateControl" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" Type="Date" MinimumValue="01/01/1900" MaximumValue="01/01/2100" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Also more information about RangeValidator here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt(v=vs.71).aspx

Sample:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_rangevalidator

Simplest way of server-side validation:

code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DateTime result;
     if (DateTime.TryParse(DatePicker.Text, out result))
     {
           //handle results
     }
     else
     {
           // e.g. highlight DatePicker or handle error
     }
 }
```

Form:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DatePicker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

Jquery validation sample:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: new Date(2013, 0, 01),maxDate: new Date(2013, 04, 01), dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd"});
  }); <!-- select only date from 1 jan 2013 to 1 may 2013 --!>
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My javascript function which I use only to display alert message.  function Redirect(opt) {
            if (opt == "validate") {
                alert("Holiday already entered for this date...! Choose another date");
            }
            shouldsubmit = true;
            window.location.assign("SetHolidays.aspx");
        }

Comment: My server side code for saving.
    `Dim dsGetHolDetails = dbl.usp_GetHolidaysForView().CopyToDataTable`
        `ViewState("HolidayDetails") = dsGetHolDetails`
        `Dim dtHols As New DataTable`
        `dtHols = CType(ViewState("HolidayDetails"), DataTable)`
        `For i = 0 To dtHols.Rows.Count - 1`
            `While dtHols.Rows(i)(2).ToString = txtHolidayDate.Text`
                `Dim script As String = String.Format("Redirect('{0}')", "validate")`
                `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, GetType(Page), UniqueID, script, True)`

Comment: You should add tag "VB" to your post

Comment: Igor, let me make it clear to you. I am NOT going to validate based on range. It is just I have some dates in the table like 01/04, 02/04, 03/04 etc., The new date or the existing one which I am going to save should NOT be equal to the ones in the database i.e, I need the code to check every single records's date column.

Comment: I have got it, thanks all :) I just wrote a code, calling the stored procedure which fetches the list of holidays saved in the table. Like `Dim a = <stored procedure>` So, IF a.count > 0 I write an alert message.