# Unable to call server side function using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have the following code in jquery

```
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Appointment.aspx/saveAppointment",
                data: "{firstname:'" + firstname + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(1);
                    // Do something interesting here.
                }
            });
        });
```

I am calling this function in vb.net

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function saveAppointment(ByVal firstname As String) As Boolean

    Dim checkval = globalclass.firstname
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

End Class

It seems to work without any parameters. There is no call if the parameters are provided. I also referred  this but does seem to work

[Calling an ASP.NET server side method via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886903/calling-asp-net-server-side-method-via-jquery)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

to post data as object:

> data Type: PlainObject or String Data to be sent to the server. It is
>   converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to
>   the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this
>   automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an
>   Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the
>   value of the traditional setting (described below).

```
data: {firstname: firstname}
```

or

```
data: {firstname: firstname}  // in case you want to assign "firstname" as string value        to the data you are posting.
```

considering `firstname` on the right side is a defined variable in your javascript , while the `firstname` on left side is the name you will use in the other side script ( PHP , vb.net ... etc )

Comment: I tried that but even this didn't work. I most used the above method when I worked. Used it assign it entities in separate file. The following code seems to be working -

    data:  '{firstname:'+ '"' + firstname + '"' + '}',

Comment: @user2165764 im not experienced with vb.net but seems that the problem is with your vb script even if it works , the ajax data syntax is invalid. Unless you are posting the whole string for example if firstname = "xxx" , then you must be posting : "{firstname:'xxx'}"

Comment: I think the Vb is fine. Even for the function with function with no parameters I had to pass the values as Data: "{}" ; else the function wasn't called. I am kind of confused now as that's not how I remember jquery. Ideally your code should have worked. Still looking. Will update here if I find a reason.

Comment: if you pass data as "{}" , it means you are passing a string not an object.